# Confirmation of connection between TSAL5300 IR sensor and BPW34 photodiode

Tags: sensor, infrared, photodiode

[image]I need to check whether my NIR LED sensor and BPW34 photodiode connection are correct or not. Does my IR sensor have to be infront of the photodiode?

I am going to place my finger on the IR sensor to detect my glucose level where photodiode will convert the attenuated light into voltage. But even if I turn  on a flashlight and shine it on the 2 sensors, the reading doesn't change. Anode of photodiode is connected to ground, cathode of photodiode is connected to A0, 1k resistor and VCC(5V). Anode of IR sensor is connected to 1k resistor and VCC(5V) and cathode of IR sensor is connected to ground.

[image]

Comment: Can you draw a schematic diagram instead of a wiring diagram?  Anyone inclined to help you would have to translate your wiring diagram to a schematic - more people will try to help if they don't have to make that extra step.

Comment: okay, i will try because i m not familiar with schematic drawing

Comment: any schematic drawing website that include arduino nano?

Comment: Fritzing can produce schematic diagrams as well as wiring diagrams.

Comment: the schematic not sure is correct or not thats why i didnt use it at first

Comment: You schematic, the wiring diagram, and the description don't match.

Comment: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments." this comment section cannot be too many? Replying JRE, yes thats why i didnt show schematic at 1st, or is it breadboard diagram have wrong at 1st which leads to schematic not match?

Comment: Your assumption that this design is adequate is wrong.  Sensor design is not adequate.  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6116315/

Comment: Oh i see, because i am following this http://www.ijettjournal.org/Volume-67/Issue-3/IJETT-V67I3P223.pdf maybe thats why

Comment: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=151824.0 and this

Comment: @John:  The PDF doesn't include a description of the circuit, let alone a diagram.  The one photo is too fuzzy to tell how things are connected.

Comment: so what can i do?